# "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous" when using .apply() over DataFrame, but OK if applied over Series

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame with a bunch of military/integer times, which I'm converting to `datetime.time()` objects using a user-defined function. The dataframe looks like this:

```
|    |   SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE |   DEPARTURE_TIME |   ARRIVAL_TIME |
|---:|----------------------:|-----------------:|---------------:|
|  0 |                  1510 |             1458 |           1747 |
|  1 |                  1100 |             1056 |           1402 |
|  2 |                  1303 |              nan |            nan |
|  3 |                  1555 |             1554 |           1829 |
|  4 |                  1657 |             1644 |           1827 |
```

Since there are NaNs in the data, I had to include a condition to skip nulls. This is the function:

```py
def make_time(x):
    if pd.isnull(x):
        return(np.nan)
    hour = math.floor(x/100)
    minute = math.floor(x%100)
    out = datetime.time(hour,minute)
    return(out)
```

When I run `df['column'].apply(make_time)` everything works well, but when applying the function to the whole table using `df.apply(make_time, axis=0)`, I get the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I believe this is because of that conditional within the 'make_time' function, but **it only happens when applying the function to the DataFrame instead of each Series**. Is there a way to avoid this problem without having to apply the function separately for each column?

Code to generate df:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE': {0: 1510, 1: 1100, 2: 1303, 3: 1555, 4: 1657}, 
              'DEPARTURE_TIME': {0: 1458.0, 1: 1056.0, 2: np.nan, 3: 1554.0, 4: 1644.0}, 
              'ARRIVAL_TIME': {0: 1747.0, 1: 1402.0, 2: np.nan, 3: 1829.0, 4: 1827.0}})
```

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but would `df.apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%H%M')` and ignoring the date part work for you?

Comment: (or even something a bit ugh-ish like: `df.apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%H%M').applymap(lambda v: v.time() if pd.notna(v) else v)`)

Comment: how about  using `applymap` ike`df.applymap(make_time)` or `df.stack().map(make_time).unstack()`

Comment: @JonClements it probably would haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrame.apply` operates over whole columns or rows and so in your code:

```
def make_time(x):
    if pd.isnull(x):
        return(np.nan)
    # ...
```

The `x` here is a `Series` and not a single object. Your example when using `df['column_name'].apply(make_time)` works as that invokes `Series.apply` which calls your function for each element in that `Series`.

To make your code work, you can use:

```
df.applymap(make_time)
```

Which'll apply your function to each individual element (instead of by columns/rows) in the DataFrame.

Alternatively, you can also make use of some Pandas goodness and either do:

```
df.apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%H%M')
```

and ignore the date part or use the above but then extract only the time element from those, eg:

```
df.apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%H%M').applymap(lambda v: v.time() if pd.notna(v) else v)
```